# How to make unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER) succeed after chroot?

Tags: linux, chroot, unshare

My call to *unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER)* when called as a non-root user returns EPERM because of this (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unshare.2.html):

> EPERM (since Linux 3.9)
>                 CLONE_NEWUSER was specified in flags and the caller is in a
>                 chroot environment (i.e., the caller's root directory does not
>                 match the root directory of the mount namespace in which it
>                 resides).

I've used *pivot_root(2)* (at that time, running as root) rather than *chroot(2)* to get into this directory. I'verified that skipping the *pivot_root(2)* call makes *unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER)* succeed as a non-root user. But I want both: *pivot_root(2)* and *unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER)*. I've tried adding *unshare(CLONE_NEWNS)* just after the *pivot_root(2)*, but that didn't work, I'm still getting EPERM from *unshare(CLONE_NEWNS)*. How can I make it succeed?

FYI I need this because I want to create a rootless container manually inside a chroot-like environment.

Comment: NEWUSER before pivot_root(), maybe?

Comment: @sourcejedi: These are two different processes. The first process calls *pivot_root(2)* as root, then some other work is done, then another process running as non-root wants to call *unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER)*, and that one fails. How do I make that one succeed? Could you please clarfiy?

Comment: Please note you should call `chroot("/");` (or `chroot(".");` if you're chdir'd to that directory) right after `pivot_root`. Are you doing that? Can you share a small reproducer that illustrates the issue you're running into?

Comment: @pts I guess I didn't read the last sentence of your question, sorry.  I believe we can work this out if we have a small reproducer to look at, as suggested.